# React-Native the child component don't render the information within the parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I'm developing a React Native app that using a ScrollView. I want to display an amount of items (A card with title and a child component).

The problem comes when I have to render each item, while the parent renders ok, the child does not.

I don't know where could be the issue, here's my code:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

    const mismo =[
     'Mismo',
     'Mismo',
     'Mismo',
     'Mismo',
     'Mismo'
    ];


    class Mismo extends Component {


     renderMismo2(){
       mismo.map((item) =>{
       return(
         <View>
           <Text>{item}</Text>
         </View>
       )
     })
    }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
      {this.renderMismo2()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Mismo;
```

=================================

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {Card} from 'react-native-elements';

import PriceCard from '../components/PriceCard';
import Mismo from '../components/Mismo';


class OrderPricingCard extends Component{
  renderAllPrices(){
    this.props.data.orders.map((item, i) => {
      return(
        <View>
          <PriceCard
            key={item.transporterName}
            data={item}
          />
        </View>
      );
    })
  }

  renderMismo(){
    return(
      <Mismo />
    );
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Card
        containerStyle={styles.cardContainer}
        title={`Pedido: ${this.props.data.id}`}
      >
        <ScrollView
          horizontal
        >
            {this.renderMismo()}

            {this.renderAllPrices()}



        </ScrollView>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  cardContainer:{
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  }

}

export default OrderPricingCard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be an easy mistake to make! I've done it several times. What's happened is you've forgotten the `return` statement for the render methods (`renderMismo2()` and `renderAllPrices()`) found in each component. Although the `map` methods correctly have return statements, you're not actually returning anything from the functions themselves.

If you were to `console.log()` either of those function calls above the `return` in the React `render()` method, you would see `undefined` in the console.

Here's what they would look like corrected.

```
renderAllPrices(){
    // added the 'return' keyword to begin the line below
    return this.props.data.orders.map((item, i) => {
      return(
        <View>
          <PriceCard
            key={item.transporterName}
            data={item}
          />
        </View>
      );
    })
  }

 renderMismo2(){
   // same here, added the 'return' keyword
   return mismo.map((item) =>{
   return(
     <View>
       <Text>{item}</Text>
     </View>
   )
 })
}
```

I tested the above in a React Native sandbox and it works. Hope that helps!